# Create an "actIve" state for static Magento nav

Tags: css, magento, content-management-system, navigation

I created a static navigation menu in my header.phtml file.

`<li><a href="/about.html"> about</a></li> <li><a href="/store.html">store</a></li>` etc..

How do I add the class "active" to the list item if the page is active?

Thanks,
-Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magento's built-in method for this is in the navigation block class:

```
isCategoryActive($category)
```

You should be able to check it with that, though, since you've changed the template to a static nav, I'm guessing you're not using the proper models to call that function.

Comment: Your right, I'm not using Magento's built in nav system. It's just a static list.

Answer (score 0):

old post, but still might help someone:

```
$url = $category->getUrl();     
if (strpos(Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl(),$url) !== false ) {
    $html .= ' <em>&gt;</em>'; // highlight
}
```